# Nested query in streambuilder with firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of posts (`/posts`) each one referencing the id of the author (in `/users`) and I was wondering, is there a way to do a double query using a streambuilder in flutter (get the posts infos and then for each post query the users info for the `authorID`) ? And if not, what is the best way to approach this ? :)

Example of my firestore structure:

```
- posts
   - postID
      - authorID
      - text
      - timestamp
      - otherfields...

- users
   - userID
      - name
      - email
      - otherfields
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do a firestore query without another stream. How I have solved this is with `StreamZip` or nested StreamBuilders.

```
stream: new StreamZip([stream1, stream2])
```

or

```
return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().asStream(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.document('my_collection/$uid').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
```